# How to compile c language with different options with vscode?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

Some c language codes use dynamic libraries, so I need to use the `-ldm` option. Some include other static libraries and need to use `-I` to specify the directory. But in vscode, the common configuration is directly `gcc sourcefile -o targetfile`, so it can't be executed normally? Is there a way to make vscode execute according to Makefile?
And such a setting can automatically use this method when I use SSH to add a folder on the server to the workspace, without having to reconfigure it every time?

Comment: Visual Studio Community provides a more complete build environment than Visual Studio Code, so if you're working on a larger project, consider that.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/building-your-c-application-with-visual-studio-code/#Makefiles

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is possible to have VSCode work with `make` on `linux` or `msbuild.exe` on `windows`. You can have different configurations within these as well so that you have have a `Debug` build or a `Release` build. All you need to do is to have suitable tasks defined in `tasks.json`. For instance, consider:

```
        {
            "label": "lindbgbuild",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make",
            "args": [
                "CONF=Debug",
                "-C",
                "./.vscode"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "linreleasebuild",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make",
            "args": [
                "CONF=Release",
                "-C",
                "./.vscode"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "label": "winbuilddebug",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "msbuild",
            "args": [
                ".vscode/windows.vcxproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/property:Configuration=Debug",
                "/property:Platform=x64",
                "/t:build",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "winbuildrelease",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "msbuild",
            "args": [
                ".vscode/windows.vcxproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/property:Configuration=Release",
                "/property:Platform=x64",
                "/t:build",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
```

There are 4 tasks in the `tasks.json`. In turn, they are:

`lindbgbuild` which executes command `make CONF=Debug -C ./.vscode`

What this command assumes is the existence of `Makefile` in the `./.vscode` subdirectory of the current (project) directory. Then, it executes the `Debug` configuration within it. The next, `linreleasebuild` does the same for the `Release` configuration. So, what we have accomplished is that we can run an abstract command `make` and then this command will call the appropriate configuration specified within `Makefile`. All commands like `g++ -c -o -g -I`, etc., are configurable **outside** of VSCode in a separate makefile that VSCode only calls.

Then, you have a task `winbuilddebug`. This assumes the existence of a `.vcxproj` project configuration file in `./.vscode`. It then executes the appropriate configuration with the options provided (in this case, the configuration is `Debug` on `x64`). Similarly, `winbuildrelease` for `Release` configuration under Windows. `.vcxproj` is automatically generated by `Visual Studio IDE` and makefiles on `linux` can be created by getting the project built using an IDE such as `Netbeans`. Or else, you can modify pre-existing makefiles/.vcxproj from other pre-existing projects to suit your current project. (I suggest against this, and using an IDE for your initial build since that automates without error many settings.)

With this given `tasks.json`, how do you access these tasks? On hitting `CtrlShiftB`, it opens up `Select Build Tasks to Run` dialog box where you can choose which task you want to run depending on which OS/Platform/compiler you are on.

Is there a way to automate this step and launch? Indeed, following is an example of `launch.json`. Consider the following configuration:

```
        {
            "name": "(Windows)RelLaunch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": ".vscode/x64/Release/windows.exe",
            "args": [],
            "preLaunchTask": "winbuildrelease",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
        }
```

This will `build` then launch the application (assuming there are no build errors). Which build configuration does it choose? It will choose the `winbuildrelease` configuration that has been specified. Like this, if you are debugging and want to step through the code, you will have a different configuration.

How do you choose which configuration to launch? Hit `CtrlShiftD`. This opens up the `Run` sidebar, where on top, you can choose from amongst the configurations you have specified in your `launch.json`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If there are input parameters, how should I debug? For example, if I need ./runFile args1 args2 to run, how to debug with vscode?

Comment: You can enter them via args in launch.json. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1067. Should work for C/C++ as well.

Comment: Yet another way is to have a `usersettings.json` input file. You would have to restructure your code so that input parameters are read from this file via code instead of as argc and argv. That way, you can continue to launch your debug configuration and only change the `usersettings.json` file which does not need a rebuild.

Comment: I am trying to do this. Can you give me more details on how to write the usersettings.json file, and how to set the C language to use this file as input? thank you

Comment: I used $(< usersettings.json) in the args of launch.json, but it did not work

Comment: What I meant is that a `json` file is typically used to provide options. Suppose you run your code with `nCust=10` and `nSuppliers=20`, these can be placed in a user input file (for convenience I called it `usersettings.json`). Please refer to a `json` tutorial. Then, you can read the json file in using a library, such as `boost`. That way, one can avoid `argc` and `argv` and instead provide these via an input file. Since you are reading the json file in, you don't need to compile it. You can debug with nCust = 2, nSuppliers=3 and debug it.