# How to add the custom compile commands in VS Code?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, gnome-terminal, geany, vscode-keybinding

I usually do competitive programming in Geany IDE and have the following custom *compile* command to compile C++ programs -

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wshadow -Wall -o "%e" "%f" -g -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG
```

The *compile* command is binded by `f9` key. I just have to press `f9`, which saves and compiles the file and then I switch to bash terminal (`f2` key shortcut) to execute the binary file.
**The terminal also follows the path of the current file opened in editor.**

I want the same settings in VS Code.
So far, I have managed to bring the editor and terminal side by side and to easily toggle the focus between them via `f1` and `f2`.
But I am unable to set the custom *compile* command, bind it with `f9` key and to configure the terminal so that it follows the path of file in editor currently in focus.
Please give me a complete solution. It would be much better to edit the json setting files directly.
Here is a snapshot of the settings in my Geany IDE :-
[This is how my Geany looks and the Setting boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwgx6.jpg)

Comment: compilation is done by Tasks

Comment: Look at the terminal `sendSequence` command in a keybinding for the first part.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65015057/how-to-compile-c-language-with-different-options-with-vscode/65015872#65015872) from a while ago provides some details about being able to *build* on linux/windows the same project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a [`custom task`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks) in VS Code. Edit the `tasks.json` file in the `.vscode` folder of your workspace like:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "My build task",
            "type": "shell",
            // Assign output file name with VSCode inner variables like ${fileBasename}
            "command": "g++ -std=c++17 -Wshadow -Wall -o ${fileBasename} -g -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG",
            "options": {
            },
            "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can write the compile command directly into `"command"` attribute, or write it with more commands into a script then write the simple executing script command in the attribute instead.

And the `"isDefault": true` attribute make this `default task` which could be invoked simply binding with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you so much. This not only helped me but also taught me many new stuff. I added the vscode inner variable ${fileBasenameNoExtension} as output file in the build command.

Comment: Is there any tasks.json file at the user level, not just workspace.

Comment: AFAIK no, refering to the doc: "Task support is only available when working on a workspace folder...".